# Blank pages after appendices titles

Tags: spacing, appendices

I have a couple of appendices whose title is followed by a blank page before actual content starts (usually in the form of figures or tables).

Example (software.tex):

```
\chapter{Software}
\label{app:Software}
\begin{SCtable}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ p{0.22\textwidth} X }
\toprule
\textbf{Software}    & \textbf{Description, area of application} \\
\midrule
...
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption[Used software and database systems]{Used software and database systems.}
\label{tab:MethodsSoftware}
\end{SCtable}
```

This results in a blank page before the table is shown:
[image]

As far as I am concerned, the table would have more than enough space to be displayed right under the title of the appendix.

Weirdly, when the title is followed by a listing (or by text), it works as expected (code.tex):

```
\chapter{Code}
\label{app:Code}

As can be seen, in this case, the \gls{json} response consists of structured and hierarchical information about each Tweet (from line 43), including the time when the Tweet was sent in \gls{utc} (field ``created\_at'' on line 45), and information about the user (line 56--61). 

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={[An example GET request]An example GET request to the Twitter \gls{rest} \gls{api}, requesting the most recent Tweet of Justin Bieber (Retweets excluded).}, label=src:DataTwitterAPIGETRequest]
GET /1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=1&include_rts=false&screen_name=justinbieber HTTP/1.1
X-HostCommonName:
    api.twitter.com
Authorization:
    OAuth oauth_consumer_key="...",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1374664745",oauth_nonce="1635874679",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_token="...",oauth_signature="q8kravuAKfKEZXMKtY2Q\%2Bsxdgew\%3D\"
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

The appendices are included as follows:

```
\appendix
\include {./back/code}
\include {./back/software}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`begin{SCtable}` implies a [float placement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned) which you might know from graphics. The default options for the placement are `tbp` which means either at the top of the page (t) or at the bottom (b) or in a special page consisting only of floats (p).  This is useful for graphics where the exact place doesn't matter.

But you want the table to be typeset exactly at the place you specify it.  Therefore, you need to pass the parameter h (for "here").  So write:

```
\begin{SCtable}[][h]
```